# How can I count the rows of a table created from dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table containing SQL statements stored as `VARCHAR`.  I want to count how many rows each statement returns.  I'm reading the statements into a temp variable called `@SQL`, and doing something like this as I cursor through each row:

```
set @SQL = (select sqlcode from t1 where id = @id)  
set @SQL = 'Select @id, count(*) from (' + @SQL + ') as t';

insert into #myresults

exec(@SQL)
```

This works just fine unless until one of the SQL statements itself uses temp tables or cursors.

Comment: Have you tried running the statement and then grabbing the @@Rowcount?

Comment: That sounds like what I'm looking for.  I'll give it try.

Comment: The statements that are giving me trouble end with a series of 'drop table' and 'close cursor' statements, so @@rowCount returns 0.

Comment: What version of SQL are you running? There are ways of pulling rows affected from the query store if you're on a newer version

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: Then you need to look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql. Grab the last_rows column

Comment: Thanks, Doc.  I think that might do it, but I lack the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the count to a variable

```
DECLARE @mycount int
INSERT INTO #TempTable(ColumnList)
SELECT ColumnList From SomeplaceElse
SET @mycount =@@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.